# Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql

In a MySQL database I have a column in a table **`amount` DECIMAL(10,10) NULL**`. I want to write data into this column

```
 preparedStatement
            = this.getConnection().prepareStatement
            ("UPDATE wallets SET amount = ? WHERE id = ?");
    preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal("2.5");
...
```

throws an exception when trying to write data to the database

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1
```

Comment: What code comes immediately after that?

Comment: preparedStatement.setLong(2, id); preparedStatement.executeQuery();

Comment: You didn't leave enough room for the part of the number to the left of the decimal point. Try `DECIMAL(10, 9)`, if you only need 1 digit to the left.  `DECIMAL(M,D)`... "_M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65._" and "_D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M._" Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e87998df0cd1d12840f50d4601b422f0

Comment: According to your table definition, the maximum value that `amount` can store is `0.9999999999`. That means that `2.5` is definitively out of range.

Comment: `DECIMAL(10,10)` means "10 digits total, and 10 of them after decimal point". And hence none digit before decimal point. I.e. only values `-1 < value < 1` are allowed.

Comment: And that should be `executeUpdate`